# Definition of the $l_2$ space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Why do we define $l_{2}$ to be the space of real sequences $(x_{k})$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\vert x_{k} \vert^{2}$ converges instead of the space of sequences such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_{k}{}^{2}$ converges? $\vert x_{k}\vert^{2}=x_{k}^{2}$ after all...

This question may be silly, but I want to be sure there's nothing mysterious going on here.

Comment: Sometimes, one considers sequences with $x_k \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Usually, not sometimes!

Comment: Ok, the definition in my book is only for real numbers. Thank you.

Comment: @Simoes They probably didn't want you to be confused later. For real numbers, you are right that the absolute value is not needed.